# Image Mapping, CSS Sprites and jQuery showing Hidden DIV

Tags: jquery, css-sprites, imagemap

So I'm trying to use Image Mapping, CSS Sprites and jQuery to build this part of a website. Imagine a logo (image) that has 3 mapped points (first letter, middle letter and last letter). Each of these mapped regions on the image have a href of # and the jQuery shows a hidden div when each of the mapped regions are clicked on. Till this part I'm set.

Here's the stuff I can't seem to work out. I want to use some sort of JavaScript or jQuery function 'onmouseover' or something of the sort, so that once the user hovers the mouse over each specific mapped region, a text-based div shows up. Think of this as a menu. Once the mouse is over the mapped region, a little text shows up above saying "Contact" for example.

After solving that problem, I need to somehow incorporate CSS Sprites into the main mapped image. I want a 'slow' fade in sort of look to be implemented to the image once the person hovers over their mouse onto the mapped region. Basically the sprite image I have has 4 stages: 1 - neutral logo, 2 - when mapped region 1 is hovered, the rest of the logo becomes black and white, 3 - same as 2 but on mapped region 2, and 4 - same as 2 and 3 but with mapped region 3. [I couldn't find a better way to describe this].

I've read everything out there, researched through stackoverflow and other forums too but I can't seem to be able to mix and match these 3 things. My code is below, and I'd really appreciate if anyone could help out.

Let me know if more clarification is needed.
Thanks in advance

[Here](http://absolutelyunsure.com/star) is sort of what I'm working on. The DELTA's (triangles) are the mapped out regions.

### **HTML**

```
<header>
  <img src="img/starcadian.png" usemap="#logo" id="menumap" />

      <map name='logo'>
        <area shape='poly' coords='253, 66, 260, 79, 275, 135, 282, 161, 288, 172, 284, 174, 192, 175, 189, 168, 194, 162, 202, 153, 229, 103, 250, 69' href='#' alt="see" class="show_hide" id="see" />
        <div class="slidingDiv">
          <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/43356088" width="460" height="260" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
          <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/75168156" width="460" height="260" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
          <a href="#" class="show_hide">
          </a>
        </div>

        <area shape='poly' coords='875, 66, 867, 85, 851, 140, 847, 156, 839, 169, 841, 173, 846, 176, 935, 174, 939, 173, 939, 168, 934, 164, 927, 153, 906, 118, 888, 85, 878, 69' href='#' class="show_hide2" id="listen" alt="listen" />
        <div class="slidingDiv2">
          <center>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Starcadian/192863837462944?ref=hl" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-4x">
                  </i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="http://twitter.com/SunsetBlood" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x">
                  </i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="http://vimeo.com/starcadian" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fa fa-vimeo-square fa-4x">
                  </i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="https://soundcloud.com/starcadian" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fa fa-music fa-4x">
                  </i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;For general enquiries, please contact: 
              <a href="mailto:me@starcadian.com">
                me@starcadian.com
              </a>
            </p>
          </center>
          <a href="#" class="show_hide2 hide-button">
            HIDE
          </a>
        </div>
        <area shape='poly' coords='575, 26, 537, 105, 512, 163, 506, 171, 513, 175, 617, 174, 626, 191, 633, 194, 646, 194, 656, 192, 662, 186, 670, 172, 664, 159, 657, 151, 647, 148, 632, 147, 621, 121, 589, 49, 579, 28' href='#' class="show_hide3" />
        <div class="slidingDiv3">
          <p>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Starcadian/192863837462944?ref=hl" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/download.png" alt="Download Code Here" />
            </a>
          </li>
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/starcadian/id481719231" target="_blank">
            <img src="img/itunes.png" alt="iTunes" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://open.spotify.com/artist/3I0ceM8qfqhCKGepaswmVg" target="_blank">
            <img src="img/spotify.png" alt="Spotify" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://starcadian.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">
            <img src="img/bandcamp.png" alt="Bandcamp" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="show_hide3 hide-button">
        HIDE
      </a>
</div>
</map>
</header>
```

### **jQuery**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {  

            $(".slidingDiv").hide();
            $(".show_hide").show();
                $('.show_hide').click(function(){
                $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
            });

            $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
            $(".show_hide2").show();
                $('.show_hide2').click(function(){
                $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
            });

                $(".slidingDiv3").hide();
            $(".show_hide3").show();
                $('.show_hide3').click(function(){
                $(".slidingDiv3").slideToggle();
            });
            // all jQuery code goes here  
        });
    </script>
```

** It wouldn't allow me to post the CSS in here so I just [JsFiddle'd it here](http://jsfiddle.net/SE4tk/).

Comment: hover part is fairly simple, not sure where div needs to show up or where content comes from for it. Start there and narrow down more details. Also, create very simple html and css working demo in jsfiddle with real `area` tags. Could use pic from your site or a flickr pic or whatever. Need a starting point to help with. Doesn't need to be fancy

Comment: sprites part is very confusing...not clear at all what intentions are there